# Optimizing identification of tree stand boundaries

Tags: qgis-3, dem, vectorization, generalization, forest-ecology

I am working on a workflow to identify tree stand boundaries. My desired result is the blue lines - I know it will never be like that, but I need it to be as good as possible. My best result is the red lines. The final result must not be polygons, but lines.

[image]

So this is what I have done so far:
I am using a Normalized DSM with pixel-size 2x2 as my starting layer.
This is my workflow:
[image]

I use `i.segment` where my best results have been with Difference Threshold=0.4 and Minimum Number of cells = 150.
Then I use `r.to.vect` because Polygonize for some reason didn't work in this workflow (?).
After this I convert to lines, and delete duplicates.
I use line simplification with Tolerence 8.5 (best result)
And last I use `v.generalize` with Maximal Tolerance Value=21 with the Douglas algorithm.

So I use four variables to make my result better. I have tried to use some more of the other variables, but honestly I am not sure how they affect the result.

So I am asking here for any suggestions to make my result better?

Update:
I managed to make it slightly better by keep changing the variables above.
I tried some other variables:

- In segmentation I changed the amount of memory to use in MB, but it had no effect.
- In `v.generalize` i tried all different algorithms, and Douglas appears to be the best.
- I also tried changing the Look-ahead parameter in `v.generalize`, but it had no positive effect.

So I am still hoping for any "out-of-the-box" suggestions to make it better.

Update-2:
I am still working on this.
I have tried different variations for raster inputs.
I have tried the following:

1. Normalized DSM (resolution 2x2)
2. Normalized DSM (2x2) + orthofoto
3. Normalized DSM (2x2) + orthofoto + Orthofoto CIR
4. Orthofoto + Orthofoto CIR
5. Normalized DSM (2x2) + DSM (2x2)

I have also tried different resolutions, but 2x2 gives the best result.
I have also learned that combining three raster inputs gives a worse result.
My best results is either just using Normalized DSM (2x2) or the combined input with Normalized DSM (2x2) + DSM (2x2).

Still hoping for some suggestions. I am open for trying an other open source product.

Comment: Right now I am trying with more inputs,as you wrote. But its back to zero in many ways. So I am working with that.
If you have an other open source solution, I am open to try it.

Answer (score 9):

I had a go with some simple Python. Hope this is still acceptable.
Basically, I did a bit of blurring (Gaussian smoothing, you can blur the image more or less to make the homogeneous areas more homogeneous), and then applied a segmentation algorithm. My script is heavily based on some [scikit-image documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_segmentations.html), and this is what I get in terms of segments:

[image: segmentation results]

You can of course tweak the parameters, and if you wanted to save the output as an e.g. GeoTIFF you could then extract polygons from, just save the `segments_slic` as GeoTIFF with the appropriate geolocation. I left that bit of the code commented out at the end.

```py
# Big import block
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.segmentation import slic
from skimage.segmentation import mark_boundaries

# Open image
im_fp = Image.open("forest.png")
# Turn into numpy array, discard last band
# (alpha channel?)
img = np.asarray(im_fp)[:, :, :-1]

# Smooth spatially a bit
img=ndi.gaussian_filter(img, sigma=5)

# Calculate segments. 
# Feel free to tweak n_segments, compactness
# and sigma
segments_slic = slic(img, n_segments=25, compactness=50, 
                     sigma=1, start_label=1)

# Plot image and boundaries
plt.imshow(mark_boundaries(img, segments_slic))

# Export as GeoTIFF. Check
#drv = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')     # create driver for writing geotiff file
#outRaster = drv.CreateCopy('forest_segments.tif', 'forest.tif, , 0 )   # create new copy of inut raster on disk
#outRaster.SetGeoTransform([top_left_x, hor_resolution, 0, top_left_y, 0, -vert_res])
#outRater.SeProjection()
#newBand = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)                               # get the first (and only) band of the new copy
#newBand.WriteArray(segments_slic)                                           # write array data to this band 
#outRaster = None
```

Comment: any rule of thumb on how to optimise the choice of SLIC parameters (e.g. segments, compactness)?

Comment: `n_segments` is roughly the number of patches on the image, `compactness`  is basically a tradeoff between square pixels and the underlying data. Choose a lower `compactness` for less blocky patches, and viceversa. `sigma`: smoothing kernel width. I already applied a sigma of 5, but maybe not needed? All options [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html?highlight=slic#skimage.segmentation.slic)